# django: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Tags: python, django, datetime

I created a list of values of datetime objects

```
a=design_list.values_list('date_submitted')
```

So I get:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 21, 13, 56, 24),), (datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 21, 10, 33, 58),), etc...
```

I'm trying to convert them to timestamps with, say:

```
timestamps[0] = a[0].strftime("%s")
```

But I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added flat=True to the query:

```
a=design_list.values_list('date_submitted', flat=True)
```

Which gives:

```
[datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 21, 13, 56, 24), datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 21, 10, 33, 58),
```

Which then can be converted.

Answer (score 5):

You're referring to the tuple instead of the first element of the tuple. Try `a[0][0].strftime('%s')`.

```
>>> a = [(datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 21, 13, 56, 24),)]
>>> a[0][0].strftime('%s')
'1350852984'
```

This is the reason for why you got the error, but as you correctly pointed out, flattening the resulting list is the right approach here.

Comment: @babbaggeii No prob - more of a conceptual point I guess - your approach of flattening the list beforehand is the right way to go :)